# C and C++ executables freeze in Lion, remotely hosted on Ubuntu box

Tags: terminal, performance, gcc

I'm trying to compile and run some very simple C and C++ code in Lion.  Compilation works fine.  Running the executable leads to the 'spinning beach ball of death.'  Force-quitting out of Terminal works, but I cannot reopen Terminal, and have to restart.

This works fine on my Ubuntu box.  Any ideas would certainly be appreciated.

Update:  The source and executables were stored on a remotely mounted Ubuntu box.  Trying to run a Mac-compiled executable stored on this remote server led to the beach ball.

Comment: Please post the source of a program that hangs up Terminal.  I have a rough idea about what may be happening but need to see source to confirm.  I'm compiling and running hideously complex code under Lion, so I doubt the problem is with the compiler.

Comment: Yeah, I should have posted the source, but the problem is the Ubuntu server the code and executable are stored on.  Just found out the executable is fine if it is compiled and run on my own hard drive.  Something to do with the difference between file systems?  I hadn't thought about this.

Comment: If this is something you can replicate, it might be interesting to see why it happens. Reboot, run only terminal, run this program. Is that alone sufficient to hang the Mac or is the spinning ball only for terminal app?

Comment: where are the executables compiled on? OSX or Ubuntu?  I ask because Ubuntu compiled executables might not like being run in OSX...

Comment: I could compile fine with either OS, and did not mix up the executable with the OS that compiled it.  The source and executables, though, were stored on an Ubuntu box that I had remotely mounted on the Mac.  Running this executable from the remote mount led to the spinning ball.

Comment: You mentioned that the code is simple, so I'm assuming that the executables are relatively small (kb-ish?).  Have you tried simply copying the executables to your local drive and running them there?

Comment: Sorry for the late response.  The problem was with compiling and executing code for Mac, stored on an Ubuntu system.  Copying the code over the Mac made it work.  Difference in file systems, maybe?